# ScrollView doesn't entirely scroll with Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml

I have an app that displays long strings of text with the press of some buttons, the problem comes when I display a lot of text and the ScrollView just stops scrolling for some reason.

Here is the xml of my app:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/atbutt"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.089" />


    </ScrollView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/namebutt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="changename"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/titlebutt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/titlebutt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="changetitle"
        android:text="Title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/descbutt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/namebutt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/descbutt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="changedesc"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/titlebutt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/urlbutt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="changeurl"
        android:text="Url"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/atbutt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/namebutt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/atbutt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="changeat"
        android:text="Publish Date"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/contbutt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/urlbutt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titlebutt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contbutt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:onClick="changecont"
        android:text="Content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/atbutt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/atbutt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/atbutt"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have seen some people use this same method that I'm using here and it works for them just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your layout has a few things that look wrong and could explain 
*undefined behaviour*.

1. change the `ScrollView` height and width to 0dp which means to respect the constraints set on the view

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        ...
```

2. Remove the constraints from the child of the `ScrollView` as `ContraintLayout` only applies rules to direct children.

```
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
            android:text=""
            />
```